# Bootstrap Dropdown scrolling alongwith Angular Routing

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, url-routing

I'm creating a website which is using bootstrap as well as angular. I'm using angular routing and loading custom views on the index page as needed. The problem I'm encountering is that due to routing, a menu dropdown in the header has stopped working.
Here's the code of the header:

```
<nav class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div uib-dropdown>
                    <a href="#side" class="btn btn-default btn-primary navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="side" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">Company Logo</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="side" class="nav navbar-nav collapse hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" uib-dropdown-menu>
                <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/stuff">Stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/list">List Example</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/contact">Contacts</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User <span class="caret"> </span> </a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hidden-xs">
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">User <span class="caret"> </span> </a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#/">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Before routing, clicking on the toggle button (visible on smaller screens only) would reference to the ul whose id is "side" and show that as a dropdown. But now since URL routing has been configured, clicking on the toggle button changes the url to #/side. I don't want this to happen because there is no URL #/side and this way the dropdown doesn't open either.
I've tried using location.hash() and $anchorScroll but that didn't work.
Including angular-ui attributes (such as uib-dropdown, uib-dropdown-menu etc) has changed the behavior of the toggle button such that it is only getting clicked now. The menu is not opening up.

Can someone explain what I have to do to get this to work? Help would be appreciated!

*EDIT*
Here's a couple of screenshots to show you what I mean:
[image: This is the initial page, notice the URL in the address bar]

[image: Now when I resize the screen and click the menu toggle button, the URL changes to reference the dropdown menu ID and breaks the UI]

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle, plunkr to showcase the same

Comment: @MandeepSingh The UI breaks when I try to put everything in plunker. I'm sorry about this, I don't know how to transfer the whole functionality of the app into a plunker

Comment: Let me attach images to show what I mean

Comment: you want to remove # ??

Comment: Can you tell me you need your url to be like 
example/side instead of example/#/side ???

Comment: No no. I want the url to remain /#/
I don't want the URL to change. I just want the dropdown show

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117590/discussion-between-mandeep-singh-and-lems).

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did to fix the problem (thank you for the help Mandeep Singh):

In the app.js file where routing is configured, I added the following snippet:

```
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
```

to make sure that whenever the toggle button is clicked, the URL is not redirected to show the id of the button. i.e now whenever the button with the id "side" is pressed to toggle the dropdown, the URL stays the same.
Other than that, I had not linked bootstrap.js and jquery with my index.html file. This was also causing problems.
The last thing which I did was to use UI Bootstrap with the tags ([See detail about this here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown))